# how to configure java web application in eclipse to reflect changes in backend jar after deploy on tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, tomcat6

I have java web project in eclipse. This project depends on other non-web project (let say backend project).
When I make a change in backend project, and then deploy web project to tomcat and start tomcat, changes don't appears. 
It works only following way:
I have to build backend.jar, copy it to web project web-inf/lib directory, and then deploy it on tomcat and run it.

java se6, tomcat 6, eclipse 3.7

Do you know how to handle this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So right click on your web project -> properties -> Deployment Assembly.

There is possibility to "add". And you can choose folder, jar or project. After it, remove and add back you web project to web server. Than you should see small arrow next to your project. When you click on it, all referenced projects appears. And that is it.

Maybe is also important on backend projects setup facet "Utility Module".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the problem, but... If you want to have the changes in "backend project" seen by your web project, the web project has to contain the updated backend project jar.

I have several projects like this, and typically I build the backend project which creates backend.jar. If Tomcat is running, I will stop it. Then, I will build the web project (it has a dependency on the backend.jar). The web project will produce it's output folders, including placing the new backend.jar in the WEB-INF/lib directory. When Tomcat is started, the new backend.jar changes are visible.

Is your web application build not picking up a new backend.jar?

Comment: If you wish to avoid investing time in a build system such as Maven, this seems like a reasonable solution, of course, the nicest solution would be to use something like Maven or Ant to automatically build the web project using the most recent version of backend.jar

Comment: Yes, you understand to my problem very well. Everything we have the same, problem is only that in WEB-INF/lib I still see old jar there. Do you manually copy there?

Comment: Is it possible that the project doesn't know that a new jar is available? Are you cleaning out WEB-INF/lib with each build so it is forced to pick up a new jar? Are you incrementing some sort of version number on the jar so it picks up a new one (I use ivy, and sometimes use version numbers on the backend jars to ensure I get the latest). To answer your question directly, I do NOT copy the jar manually.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you are using ivy, which provides this functionality (copy jars, taking care about dependencies).             So Eclipse itself is not possible do that.

Answer (score 0):

Activate `Project->Build Automatically`.
You only have to publish to tomcat every time you make changes to your depended projects.