# Developing two related Projects in Eclipse for Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, web-applications

I have two projects in Eclipse. One Project is a dynamic web project which is deployed on the integrated tomcat server everytime i make changes to it (which works great).

The second project is a library project which currently needs to be build with ant. The resulting .jar file needs to be copied manually to the first project's `WEB-INF/lib` directory and the whole project needs to be refreshed, rebuilt and the tomcat needs to be restarted.

Is there a way to connect the library project to the web project so that changes made to the library will be automatically deployed to the web project? This would make the whole development process a lot easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your webapp project go to properties. Under "Deployment Asselmbly" you can add your other project. So it's automaticaly added to your WEB-INF/lib folder.

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332871/how-to-configure-java-web-application-in-eclipse-to-reflect-changes-in-backend-j).